# jQuery each element in given div with class

Tags: javascript, dom, each

I have a little question. I try to build this simple quiz. Right now it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="pytanie">
        <p class="tresc">1. Ile księżyców ma ziemia?</p>
        <p class="odpowiedz">A) 1</p>
        <p class="odpowiedz">A) 2</p>
        <span class="btn-sprawdz" id="btn-sprawdz-1">Sprawdź</span> 
        </div>
        <div class="pytanie">
        <p class="tresc">1. Ile księżyców ma ziemia?</p>
        <p class="odpowiedz">A) 1</p>
        <p class="odpowiedz">A) 2</p>
        <span class="btn-sprawdz" id="btn-sprawdz-1">Sprawdź</span> 
        </div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var score;
            score=0;
            // Mechanizm zaznaczania odpowiedzi
            $('.odpowiedz').click(function() {
                // Najpierw odznacz zaznaczone odpowiedzi
                $('div.pytanie p').each(function(){
                    $(this).css('background-color','white');
                });
                // Zaznacz tę odpowiedź
                $(this).css('background-color','blue');
                });
                //Mechanizm sprawdzania
                $('#btn-sprawdz-1').click(function() {
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is obvious - when I click any question it changes the `background-color` of all `p` elements in all `div.pytanie`'s. I know that I can use the `id` selector, but is it necessary? Maybe there is another option to trim each loop only to one `div`?

Comment: This is not what i exacly need - this solution clear all p elements in all questions - maybe you made some minor mistake? Thanks for help anyway :)

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/cHktk/2/

Comment: You have multiple elements with id `btn-sprawdz-1`.

Comment: @NOX yes it is only for testing purpose (more than 1 question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var score;
    score=0;
    // Mechanizm zaznaczania odpowiedzi
    $('.odpowiedz').click(function() {
        // Najpierw odznacz zaznaczone odpowiedzi
        $(this).closest('.pytanie').find('p.odpowiedz').css('background-color','white');
        // Zaznacz tę odpowiedź
        $(this).css('background-color','blue');
    });
    //Mechanizm sprawdzania
    $('#btn-sprawdz-1').click(function() {

    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nhg77/)

Comment: `+1` It's better to make `white` only `.odpowiedz` elements ;)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/BXstL/)**</kbd>

You must get all `.odpowiedz` in the current question, for this go up to your `.pytanie`
and then select all `.odpowiedz`:

```
$(this)
    // go up the dom to the current question
    .closest('.pytanie')

    // and now find all possible answers
    .find('.odpowiedz')

        // and make them white
        .css('background-color', 'white');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible with parent() selector.

```
$('.odpowiedz').click(function() {
   $(this).parent(); // <div class="pytanie">
   $(this).parent().css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

Comment: My JS part looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/aL9Hb/ it is not work and i dont have any idea why? It shuld first set all bg-color to whit and then just set that one p bg-color to blue? Where Im wrong?

Comment: It's working, but it was setting white background while it had white bg already :) http://jsfiddle.net/aL9Hb/1/

Answer (score 1):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZquH/1/) will set the clicked `.odpowiedz` in the current div to a blue background.

```
$('.odpowiedz').click(function () {
    // Najpierw odznacz zaznaczone odpowiedzi
    $(this).parent().find(".odpowiedz").css('background-color', 'white');
    // Zaznacz tę odpowiedź
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

Comment: this also is working like a charm. Thanks for time and advice.